# Организация полнотекстного поиска

Tags: база-данных, полнотекстовый-поиск

Не могу пока сообразить, как (вернее в каком виде) построить индекс(ы) для организации полнотекстного поиска по документам. Если есть варианты - прошу поделиться.

**Исходные данные**

- Документы помещаются в таблицу в виде BLOB'ов;
- Перед занесением в таблицу - документ сжимается по алгоритму LZMA и/или PPMd/PPMz, в зависимости чем сожмется лучше;
- Нужно обеспечить поиск по части слова. Например, по строке поиска "мам" должен быть найден документ, содержащий "Мама мыла раму";
- Нужно обеспечить сортировку найденных документов в зависимости от "расстояния" между найденными словами. Например, по строке поиска "мама рам", среди найденных документов "Мама мыла раму" и "Мама мыла белую раму" - первый документ в сортировке должен быть выше, так как между "мама" и "рам" у него слов меньше, чем во втором;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Можно [последовать примеру PostgreSQL](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/datatype-textsearch.html#datatype-tsvector)

В нём для полнотекстового поиска используется **GIN-индекс** по **`tsvector`'ам** документов. Сами `tsvector`'ы хранить большой необходимости нет... с одной оговоркой, о ней далее.

- **`tsvector`** это отсортированный массив *основ слов* (слов, обработанных **стеммером**) из документа.

  - Он отсортирован ради ускорения поиска и не содержит одинаковых слов по нескольку раз, поэтому ещё и меньше места занимает.
  - **Стеммер** преобразовывает разные формы одного слова в одинаковые строки, так обеспечивается поиск с учётом разных форм одних и тех же слов. Он обычно сильно специфичен для конкретного языка, как алгоритмами, так и словарями.
  - Обычно они ещё фильтруются от стоп-слов (которые не отражают содержание документа и нужны больше для структуры), потому что в поиске от них больше вреда, чем пользы. Разумеется, тоже зависит от языка.
- GIN-индекс это отображение из отдельных элементов некоего значения (в котором есть много элементов, вроде массива, коим является и `tsvector`) в множества строк, в значениях которых эти элементы имеются. То есть, дерево поиска, в котором ключ это *основа слова*, а значение это множество идентификаторов документов.

  Имея `tsvector` запроса, поиск по описанному индексу производится путём [свёртки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) (fold, reduce) пересечением отдельных множеств из индекса по элементам `tsvector` из запроса.

  - PostgreSQL на самом деле использует для запросов другой тип, `tsquery`, с поддержкой операторов поиска, но я рассматриваю упрощённый случай.

Описанное решение, впрочем, **никак не учитывает ранжирования по расстоянию между словами**, но это весьма непросто проверять эффективно. Во всяком случае, сходу я ничего назвать не могу.

Сходу в голову приходит только сортировка по расстоянию Левенштейна между **`tsvector`'ами без сортировки** (массивами основ слов без стоп-слов) запроса и совпадения. Но мне это видится очень неэффективным решением, особенно для больших документов (на них Левенштейн будет фактически сортировать по возрастанию размера).

Comment: Спасибо, учту! На соседнем ресурсе посоветовали еще почитать "Суффиксное дерево", "Инвертированный индекс", "Поисковый индекс". Хотя с первого взгляда GIN и "Инвертированный индекс" похожи, но в вики это разные статьи. Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Majestio это чистейший инвертированный индекс. В википедии про GIN написан какой-то трэш, если честно :D Его можно и к обычным массивам применять, не только в полнотекстовом поиске.

Comment: Ну да) Вот и я приметил это)

Comment: @Majestio что касается "суффиксного дерева"... да, наверное, можно сделать суффиксное дерево из основ слов отдельных документов (вместо традиционных букв отдельных слов) и делать для быстрого вычисления веса обход по этому дереву с ограниченными пропусками. Но у меня в голове это пока выглядит скорее как "туманная идея".